# Delegates in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am trying to use delegate concept to dynamically AddHandler to different events, i.e.
instead of doing

```
AddHandler tmrA.Elapsed, AddressOf tmrA_Tick
AddHandler tmrB.Elapsed, AddressOf tmrB_Tick


    Private Sub tmrA_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs)
' something here

    End Sub

    Private Sub tmrB_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs)
' something here

    End Sub
```

I was trying to do:

```
  Private Delegate Sub dlgtAB(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs)
```

and then

```
Private Sub Test(ByRef tmr as Timer, dlgt as dlgtAB, intInterval as integer)
    tmr = New Timer(intInterval)
    AddHandler tmr.Elapsed, dlgtAB ' getting error right here on dlgtAB
End Sub
```

getting  the following error: Error      15      Value of type 'dlgtAB' cannot be converted to 'System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler'.

can you tell me if this can be done and what is it that I am doing wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't declare your own delegate type - use the `ElapsedEventHandler` type:

```
Private Sub Test(ByRef tmr as Timer, dlgt as ElapsedEventHandler, intInterval as integer)
```

This will allow you to assign the appropriate handler, as the types will match.